# Stream logs to event hub

Tags: azure, logging, cloud, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

Is there a way to send the Cloud Service(extended support) or (classic) diagnostics logs directly to event hub? When I try to enable the diagnostics from Visual Studio the only options available to send the logs are Storage account and Application Insights.
[Configuration example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goKo0.png)

Comment: [Stream Azure Active Directory logs to an Azure event hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-azure-monitor-stream-logs-to-event-hub) and [Stream Azure monitoring data to an event hub or external partner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my case was to export the logs to a storage account and then I  created a blob trigger function that ingested the logs into event hub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).